All GTK/VTE-based terminal emulators are showing a significant input lag
Recently, I've installed a new SSD drive and deployed Ubuntu 22.04.04 on it. At first everything was perfect, but then I noticed that gnome-terminal has a significant input lag (up to a second) even for signals (e.g. Ctrl-C). I had tried a few of other GTK/VTE terminal emulators (i.e. gnome-console, xfce4-terminal and terminator) with the same result, while non-VTE terminals were perfectly fine (i.e. konsole, suckless st, kitty).
I would like to return to using gnome-terminal, but this issue annoys me a lot and I have no idea where to begin the investigation. Does anyone have any debug ideas? Thank you in advance.
dt@dt-535:~$ uname -a
Linux dt-535 6.5.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Mar 12 10:22:43 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

UPDATE
Looks like it's a duplicate for this known Ubuntu issue.

See A look at terminal emulators, part 2 for a speed comparison of terminals.

Ubuntu messed up their mutter package. They're aware of the issue and are working on releasing a fix. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1509058/input-delay-on-terminal-ubuntu-22-04-4 .

@harrymc VTE (more precisely, its version as of 6 years ago when that article was written) might have been somewhat worse in some aspects of performance than some others, but definitely by no means "significant input lag (up to a second)" as OP claims. It's not that.

For any users looking for a quick fix to this issue, I have found that Konsole is not GTK/mutter-based and is not suffering from this issue. Konsole can be installed on Gnome through the software store.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
